# fields_for builder .object method does not allow me to retrieve object values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I've got 3 models that comprise a has-many-through association.

Model code as follows:

`ItemAttrVal` Model (the transition table)

```
class ItemAttrVal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attr_name
  belongs_to :registry_item
end
```

`RegistryItem` Model

```
class RegistryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_attr_vals
  has_many :attr_names, :through => :item_attr_vals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_attr_vals, :allow_destroy => :true
end
```

`AttrName` Model

```
class AttrName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_attr_vals
  has_many :registry_items, :through => :item_attr_vals
end
```

The `RegistryItem` uses a `fields_for` as follows:

```
<%= item.fields_for :item_attr_vals do |iav| %>
    <%= render 'item_attr_val_fields', :f => iav %>
<% end %>
```

In the partial, it looks like this:

```
<% logger.debug "object type is: #{f.object}"%>
<% logger.debug "some details are: #{f.object.attr_name_id}--"%>
<%= f.select :attr_name_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AttrName.all,"id","description"), :selected => f.object.attr_name_id, :prompt => "Select an attribute" %>
<%= f.text_field :raw_value %> <br />
```

The 1st 2 debug lines are the bit that my question is about, but it first relates to the 3rd line.
There, I am attempting to provide the dropdown select field with a "pre-selected" value. This is so that when the user is editing the RegistryItem, their previously selected AttrName will be displayed.

I'm attempting to use the `f.object.attr_name_id` to set that value, however it does not actually properly select the previously selected value, and instead, just goes to the 1st.

The 1st two debug lines were then me trying to make sure that my `f.object` method worked...

When I looked in my logs, I see the following:

```
object type is: #<ItemAttrVal:0x007fb3ba2bd980>
some details are: --
```

Basically, the 1st line shows me that I am getting the ItemAttrVal
The second line does not seem to retrieve any information for it.

I've also used the debugger to check, and in there, I am able to use `display f.object.attr_name_id` to show me the exact value that I'm expecting...

This kind of comes down to two questions...

1. Why can't I retrieve the values of `f.object`?
2. Am I trying to do line 3 (`<%= f.select :attr_name_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AttrName.all,"id","description"), :selected => f.object.attr_name_id, :prompt => "Select an attribute" %>`) wrong, and there's actually a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd placed the `:selected` in the wrong location...

Original:

```
<%= f.select :attr_name_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AttrName.all,"id","description"), :selected => f.object.attr_name_id, :prompt => "Select an attribute" %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= f.select :attr_name_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AttrName.all,"id","description", f.object.attr_name_id), :prompt => "Select an attribute" %>
```

Fixing that solved my problem, the attribute names are now appearing as expected for previously saved attributes.

It still doesn't answer my original query about why I'm not able to get the values for f.object printed out, but at least the original-original problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use params[:attr_name_id] into your options_from_collection_for_select

```
<%= f.select :attr_name_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AttrName.all,"id","description", params[:attr_name_id].to_i), :prompt => "Select an attribute" %>
```

hope it helps

Comment: I've checked the params hash, and the attr_name_id does not appear in there either. I'm *guessing* it's cause I'm attempting to manage it as part of its "parent" form, as opposed to its own.

Comment: That said, I do owe you thanks, cause it was looking over your answer that made me realise that I'd placed the `:selected` option in the wrong part of the method. >.<